# Is there a shorthand syntax for a sequence of throwaway variables?

Tags: python-2.7

Let's say you have a situation like this:

```
_, _, _, substring_1, _, substring_2 = some_string.split(',')
```

Is there a shorthand way of expressing those first three sequential underscores, representing values that are to be discarded? I'm specifically wondering if such a syntactic shortcut exists, not about various ways to accomplish the same task.

Edit - I'm interested in a Python 2.7-specific answer.

Comment: Which version(s) of Python?

Comment: @jonrsharpe - python 2.7

Comment: This is a nice syntax I enjoyed very much in Prolog. I enjoy doing it in Python but as far as I know (at least in Python 2) the underscore is a normal variable not a real feature of the language and coders use it as a convention for a throwable variable. Furthermore, there seem to be good reasons of using __ (two underscores) rather than _ (see http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/style/ )

Answer (score 5):

You could just use [`str.rsplit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit) with a limit:

```
>>> s = 'a,b,c,d,e,f'
>>> s.rsplit(',', 3)  # i.e. split on at most three commas, from the right
['a,b,c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
>>> _, d, _, f = s.rsplit(',', 3)
>>> d
'd'
>>> f
'f'
```

---

If you upgrade to Python 3.x, you can use `*_` to absorb an arbitrary number of elements (you'll get a `SyntaxError` in 2.x, though):

```
>>> *_, d, _, f = s.split(',')
>>> d
'd'
>>> f
'f'
```

Answer (score 4):

Not a syntactic shortcut, but you might want to use the `itemgetter` function from the `operator` module:

```
from operator import itemgetter
my_pair = itemgetter(3, 5)
substring_1, substring_2 = my_pair(some_string.split(','))
```

Or, define `my_pair` to wrap the call to `split` as well:

```
def my_pair(x):
    return itemgetter(3,5)(x.split(','))

substring_1, substring_2 = my_pair(some_string)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm curious specifically about question of whether such a shortcut exists.

Comment: Actually, there are a couple - [see Jon's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33528427/135978)

Comment: @SeanVieira not in 2.7, and I think the other option I present counts as *"various ways to accomplish the same task"*

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you are using Python 3 *and* you don't care if there are more or less than 3 entries before the last 3:

```
*_, first, _, second = somestring.split(',')
```

Otherwise, if you want the *last* 3 elements (regardless of how many entries the string has) you can use `str.rsplit` as [Jon points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33528427/135978):

```
_, first, _, second = s.rsplit(',', 3)
```

If you want the 3rd and the 5th elements (regardless of how many elements the string has) you can use [chepner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33528381/135978):

```
from operator import itemgetter

extract = itemgetter(3, 5)
first, second = extract(s.split(','))
```

Finally, if there *must* be six entries in the string, your best bet is to be explicit:

```
KeyFields = namedtuple('KeyFields', 'first second')

def extract_key_fields(s):
    data = s.split(",")
    if len(data) != 6:
        raise ValueError("Must provide six fields")
    return KeyFields(data[3], data[5])

key_fields = extract_key_fields(somestring)
key_fields.first   # d
key_fields.second  # f
```

Comment: Thank you - upvote for the answer. I should have specified that I'm interested in doing this in Python 2.7. I've edited the question accordingly.