# Use _ to escape more than one value in a for loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, metasyntactic-variable

Say I have the following data structure:

```
input = [(1,2,3,4,5), (1,2,3,4), (1,2,3)]
```

In a `for` loop, I want to iterate over only the first three elements in each tuple element at a time without worrying about how big the tuple is.

I know I can use `_` to achieve this, but with it I have to specify how many values I intend to drop.

Is there a way to achieve this without knowing in advance how big the tuple in question is?

I know I can do:

```
for i, j, k, _, _ in input:
    ....
```

But is there a way to get away with only one `_`? As the above will fail if the size of each subelement is not 5 (I will either get `need more than 4 values to unpack` if too small or `too many values to unpack` if too big).

I'm asking this out of curiosity, I know I can separately unpack the elements by doing:

```
for elem in input:     
    i, j, k = elem[:3]
```

I'm using Python 2.7.6.

Comment: Not a duplicate, none of the answers address my problem and this concerns Python 2 (which I would have been very happy to clarify). I'm genuinely amazed at the speed this got marked as duplicate before I was given a chance to clarify.

Comment: *"none of the answers address my problem"* - not true, http://stackoverflow.com/a/33528381/3001761 shows you could use `itemgetter` to do it. *"this concerns Python 2"* - so did the other, and the answers are clear that there isn't an unpacking option prior to 3.x. *"before I was given a chance to clarify"* - that chance hasn't ended yet, you can edit the question whenever you like (and *should*, to clarify precisely how this isn't a duplicate, if you're still not satisfied).

Comment: @jonrsharpe `itemgetter` is not what I was after as I can't just initialise it and use it in a loop, but I appreciate the replies with respect to Python 3's unpacking syntax, thought that could have been made available to Python 2 somehow.

Comment: `for i, j, k in map(itemgetter(0, 1, 2), ...):`?

Comment: ah, didn't think of applying `map` there, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do `for i, j, k, *_ in input:` in Python 3.x.

Comment: Is this possible in Python 2? Is it backported to any of Python's previous versions?

Comment: @Nobilis no, it's not. It's a syntax change, so backporting isn't possible, and it's not in `__future__`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Right, thanks, thought there was a way to achieve this in Python 2.